# WPF Context Menu custom style issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I am trying to customize context menu in WPF, and i am able to achieve it by following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296.aspx) example on MSDN. The last piece in the Jigsaw is the submenu title color (Submenu header).

If you notice both submenu has white on mouse hover but Submenu title takes the normal color of the submenu items (Item 1, Item , etc) even when it is highlighted.

What do i need to do to change its highlighted or mouse hover color.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid Height="22">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Margin="6,0,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderHost" Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" />
            <Path x:Name="RightArrow" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 0 7 L 4 3.5 Z" Fill="#49a3e1" />
            <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Right" HorizontalOffset="-4" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
            <Border x:Name="SubmenuBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="White" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#49a3e1">
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
            </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#49a3e1"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="RightArrow" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Pink"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

[image]